# pyinstaller is creating an empty Dist folder

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have python 3.6.1 32 bit and the updated pyinstaller as of 8/15/17

I've tried pyinstaller.exe --onefile xxxx.py from within the directory housing my file

also: 
pyinstaller.exe xxxx.py

and... 
pyinstaller xxxx.py

The folders are created, however, they're empty

I've uninstalled, reinstalled within scripts and restarted

Any ideas?

Comment: What system: Linux, Mac, Windows, etc??

Comment: @PaulT. I'm using Windows 10

Comment: python 3.6 isn't supported by pyinstaller according to http://www.pyinstaller.org/index.html

Comment: @ingvar ah... thank you